# javascript dont send variables to ajax just send void values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a code with many inputs number and program a code to collect all the values and pass them through ajax and receive a php file and add them to the session but this does not happen could someone tell me why? I already try several things and still nothing.

it seems that the data is not sent to the php file in ajax, is not taking and sending, someone knows why? What am I doing wrong?

```js
function realizaProceso(valorCaja1, valorCaja2,valorCaja3, valorCaja4,valorCaja5, valorCaja6,valorCaja7, valorCaja8,valorCaja9, valorCaja10,valorCaja11, valorCaja12,valorCaja13, valorCaja14,valorCaja15, valorCaja16,valorCaja17, valorCaja18,valorCaja19, valorCaja20,valorCaja21){
        var parametros = {
                "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
                "valorCaja2" : valorCaja2,
                "valorCaja3" : valorCaja3,
                "valorCaja4" : valorCaja4,
                "valorCaja5" : valorCaja5,
                "valorCaja6" : valorCaja6,
                "valorCaja7" : valorCaja7,
                "valorCaja8" : valorCaja8,
                "valorCaja9" : valorCaja9,
                "valorCaja10" : valorCaja10,
                "valorCaja11" : valorCaja11,
                "valorCaja12" : valorCaja12,
                "valorCaja13" : valorCaja13,
                "valorCaja14" : valorCaja14,
                "valorCaja15" : valorCaja15,
                "valorCaja16" : valorCaja16,
                "valorCaja17" : valorCaja17,
                "valorCaja18" : valorCaja18,
                "valorCaja19" : valorCaja19,
                "valorCaja20" : valorCaja20,
                "valorCaja21" : valorCaja21
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   'addCart2.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                        //$("#resultado").html(response);
                }
        });
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="ingrediente"]').on('change',function () { 
    var _thisVal = $(this).val();   
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#quiantitynice" + _thisVal).show();
    } else {
      $("#quiantitynice" + _thisVal).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" name="ingrediente" type="checkbox" id="ing19" value="19">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ing19">CAMARON</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="quiantitynice" id="quiantitynice19" style='position:relative;display:none'>
                                    <input class="formgroup" type="number" name="quantity19" id="quiantitynice19" min="1" value="" Style="width:45Px" placeholder="1">
                                </div>
        
        <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" name="ingrediente" type="checkbox" id="ing20" value="20">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="ing20">TOFU</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="quiantitynice" id="quiantitynice20" style='position:relative;display:none'>
                                    <input class="formgroup" type="number" name="quantity20" id="quiantitynice20" min="1" value="" Style="width:45Px" placeholder="1">
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-wy" name ="btnsubmin" type = "submit" onclick="realizaProceso($('#quiantitynice1').val(),$('#quiantitynice2').val(),$('#quiantitynice3').val(),$('#quiantitynice4').val(),$('#quiantitynice5').val(),$('#quiantitynice6').val(),$('#quiantitynice7').val(),$('#quiantitynice8').val(),$('#quiantitynice9').val(),$('#quiantitynice10').val(),$('#quiantitynice11').val(),$('#quiantitynice12').val(),$('#quiantitynice13').val(),$('#quiantitynice14').val(),$('#quiantitynice15').val(),$('#quiantitynice16').val(),$('#quiantitynice17').val(),$('#quiantitynice18').val(),$('#quiantitynice19').val(),$('#quiantitynice20').val(),$('#quiantitynice21').val());">AGREGAR</button> <!-- addToCar(''); -->
                </div>
            </div>
```

in the last file addCart.php I only receive the values of the post and I put them in session

Comment: Please describe in detail what _is_ happening. Also include the PHP that handles the ajax request and explain what debugging you have already done (inspected the request and response in your browser's developer tools, check for Javascript errors, etc)

Comment: the script receives many values but I only put 2 inputs, avoid hitting a lot of repeated code that only changes its id and name

Comment: patrick q I did not find what you asked me, I am a beginner and I have been reading about ajax and javascript and I set out to build an example but it does not work for me, the content of the ajax php file is merely to receive the variables by the post method and add them to session = $ val1 = $ _POST ['valueCaja1']; $ _SESSION ["val1"] = $ val1;

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are not doing a good job explaining _what_ isn't working.  It is also unclear what is _supposed to_ happen.  I don't see any relation between your HTML and your Javascript.  How/where is `realizaProceso()` called?

Comment: You're right I'm sorry, forget to add the button, I'm sorry I'm not very good explaining I repeat I'm new to this web and I do not have much idea what to do @PatrickQ

Comment: @PatrickQ already edit the post and add the button at the end of the html an apology friend